# How to change a model in a dependency app in my virtualenv

Tags: python, django, models

I have an app in my venv and I wish to extend the model but I don't really want to go into the venv and start editing the files.

Is it possible to extend the model and addd fields to it without editing the models file itself. I tried importing it somewhere else and adding variables, but that didn't work, at least initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply *monkey patching* the model to add a field isn't sufficient, because you'd still need that app to create a DB migration for that field to appear in the actual database. (It doesn't seem like you're trying to add a field or a behavior purely on a Python level, because for that monkey patching, or a `@property` or a [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) would have worked fine)

Let's say you do come up with a "hack/script/solution" to migrate the DB, you will be using that app in a version that is different from the official one, so in the future when you'll want to upgrade the app's version, you can run into issues.

### Fork your own version and use it as a dependency

So if you don't mind diverging* from the *upstream* official app, I would *fork* the app. Meaning I clone their repository, add my field into the model in their `models.py`, generate the DB migrations, commit all those back into the repository. Then instead of installing the official app, I install my version into the virtual environment. (`pip` can install from Git e.g., your app doesn't need to be on PyPI)

<sub>*Who knows maybe the app's maintainers will accept a pull request from you and put your changes in the official repo</sub>

### Subclass the model

If it works for you, you can also [subclass the original model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance), add the field you want. So your app can use the *extended* class you created, and the original app can use the fields/methods that already existed in its original model.

Comment: hmm, thanks for the info. I think the app will have some good developments in the future so I would like to stay with it and not mess with it too much if possible. I had an idea... the app is related to the auth_user_model by OneToOneField. Can I change the auth_user_model before the app ties itself to it? Or can I add a different "section" of profile into one of my app models and also relate it to the auth_user_model?

Comment: @deltaskelta Which model exactly do you want to change and for what purpose? Because if you can use your own `UserProfile` model that is a one-to-one with `User`, then you can simply extend `UserProfile`. Otherwise see this answer if it works for your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35198113/how-to-modify-a-django-model/35198325#35198325