# How to modify a Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

If I would like to change e.g. Django's Site module:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
```

How would I do that in my project? Do I subclass or what do I do to change or add some code to it?

Or do I just create a new model?

Comment: What do you mean with "modify"? If you need to extend `Site`, subclassing is the way.

Comment: If I where to change an existing field in the Django model. Like i comment below in bakkal's answer.

Comment: In fact, you cannot do that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted.

Comment: You'll either need to subclass `Site`, leave the `name` field as already is and create a new field (say, `custom_name`), leaving the first one unused, or create your own model from scratch.

Comment: In fact, the question has an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344751/in-django-model-inheritance-does-it-allow-you-to-override-a-parent-models-a)

Comment: OK, maybe the best solution is then to create a new Site model? @LostMyGlasses

Comment: If you need to modify a field of `Site`, then yes, I'd do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You can add a field via inheritance

If you still need to keep a reference to the original Site object/row, you can use [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance)

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

class MySite(Site):
    new_field = models.CharField(...)

    def new_method(self):
        # do something new
```

This allows you to have regular `Site` objects, that may be extended by your `MySite` model, in which case you can e.g. access the extra fields and methods through `site.mysite`, e.g. `site.mysite.new_field`.

### Through model inheritance, you cannot alter an ancestor field

Through inheritance you cannot hide ancestor fields, because [Django will raise a FieldError if you override any model field in any ancestor model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted).

And I wouldn't venture and write a custom DB migration for this, because then if you update Django, you may get schema conflicts with the Site model.

So here's what I would do if I wanted to store more info that the ancestor model allows:

```
class SiteLongName(Site):
    long_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

Comment: Okey, that's pretty nice. Though I still wonder if I need to change a field in the Site model that's currently: `name = models.CharField(_('display name'), max_length=50)` to change the `max_length=60` instead. How do I do that? Just add it again in the new multi-table inheritance?