# Django, override django.contrib.* models

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to add a field to a model in django.contrib.* application without monkeypatching it? 
I need to add a *description CharField* to `django.contrib.auth.models.Permission`. How to make it properly?

**UPD**: I want to show and edit additional field 'description' in default django.contrib.admin detail view for Permission model (/admin/auth/permission/) I know about python class inheritance, but how to make django.contrib.admin use child model?

Comment: Subclassing is the way.

Comment: @LostMyGlasses I know about subclassing in python. Just can't realize how to use it in my case. Can you provide an example?

Comment: `class MyPermissionModel(Permission)`, then just define it like its any other model

Comment: @svfat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35198113/how-do-i-modify-a-django-model/35198325#35198325